# How to find tempdb reside in drive location with drive size and tempdb usage details in single query in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

How to find tempdb reside in drive location with drive size and tempdb used details  in single query in sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below can be used for any database, of course the database name in `USE` command has to be changed.

```
USE tempdb;

SELECT
    [Disk] = LEFT(vs.volume_mount_point,16)
    ,[DBName] = DB_NAME()
    ,[FileName] = f.name
    ,[Size] = ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(12,2),round(f.size/128.000,2)),0)
    ,[SpaceUsed] = ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(12,2),round(fileproperty(f.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2)),0)
    ,[SpaceFree] = ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(12,2),round((f.size-fileproperty(f.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.000,2)),0)
    ,[DiskFree] = ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(12,2),vs.available_bytes/1024/1024),0)
    ,[DiskTotalSize] = ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(12,2),vs.total_bytes/1024/1024),0)

FROM sys.database_files f
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(DB_ID(), f.file_id) vs
ORDER BY f.name
```

Comment: Good script but i need logical disk drive total size in above query.

Comment: @PhanindraPothuri, I've updated the answer

Comment: Great! Is it possible to shrink tempdb dynamically and run every one hour to check tempdb size.If it reaches threshold then automatically shrunk tempdb? for eg:- suppose temdb resides in F drive contains 100GB. Tempdb occupied 80% of disk space then it should automatically shrink and reclaim space.

Answer (score 0):

This information can be found using the management DMVs [sys.master_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [sys.dm_db_file_space_usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-file-space-usage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and the system function [sys.dm_os_volume_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-volume-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT vs.volume_mount_point AS [Drive],
  mf.[name] AS [File],
  mf.physical_name AS [Filename],
  mf.size*8/1024 AS [Size (MB)],
  unallocated_extent_page_count*8/1024 AS [Free Space (MB)]
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_file_space_usage fsu ON fsu.database_id = mf.database_id AND fsu.file_id = mf.file_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.file_id) vs
WHERE DB_NAME(mf.database_id) = 'tempdb'
```